# How can I set the url for the form to POST using the FormBuilder in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I'm dynamically loading different form classes in my Controller and displaying them in my template.  This works fine, except that the Symfony2 docs show adding the route for the form to POST to in the template by hand.

```
<form action="{{ path('task_new') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I need to set that form action in the FormBuilder class-- the POST routes (e.g. 'task_new') are different depending on the form class I'm using.  Is there a way to set the form action url in the FormBuilder class?  How can we get {{ form_widget(form) }} to render the complete form, and not just the rows?  Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is possible out of the box -- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-http-method

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
->setAction($this->generateUrl('target_route'))
->setMethod('GET')
->add('task', 'text')
->add('dueDate', 'date')
->add('save', 'submit')
->getForm();
```

Comment: Works in the controller only.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem. I was using a simple `FormType` class and wanted to set the action url in `buildForm` function. I tried different things, but couldn't do it that way.

Eventually I used a Form option called 'action'. I don't think it's documented in the Symfony Reference, I have found it by accident while reading some error report :).
You can set the option when creating the form within your controller like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $obj, array( 'action' => 'whatever you want'));
```

It's not as pretty as having it encapsulated in the form class, but it works..
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 13):

It's bad practice to change submit route in form type. It not form type responsibility. If you added form from not handle form route, you can just change action url in template:

```
  {{ form_start(yourForm,{action:path('yourSubmitRoute')}) }}
```

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem by injecting the router into my form type. In my application I have created a zip code search form called *ZipCodeSearchType*:

### Form Class

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
/*
 * I'm using version 2.6. At this time 2.7 has introduced a 
 * new method for the Option Resolver. Refer to the documentation 
 * if you are using a newer version of symfony.
 */
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

/**
 * Class ZipCodeSearchType is the form type used to search for plans. This form type
 * is injected with the container service
 *
 * @package TA\PublicBundle\Form
 */
class ZipCodeSearchType extends AbstractType
{   
    /**
     * @var Router
     */
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        //Above I have a variable just waiting to be populated with the router service...
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('zipCode', 'text', [
                'required' => true,
            ])
            /*
             * Here is where leverage the router's url generator
             */
            //This form should always submit to the ****** page via GET
            ->setAction($this->router->generate('route_name'))
            ->setMethod("GET")
        ;
    }

    ...
}
```

The next step is to configure your form as a service, and let symfony know that you need the router service injected into your class:

### Define Form as Service

```
/*
 * My service is defined in app/config/services.yml and you can also add this configuration
 * to your /src/BundleDir/config/services.yml
 */
services:
    ############
    #Form Types
    ############
    vendor_namespace.zip_search_form:
        class: VENDOR\BundleNameBundle\Form\ZipCodeSearchType
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: zip_code_search }
```

### Use It In Your Controller

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Form
 */
private function searchByZipAction(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $zipForm = $this
        ->createForm('zip_code_search', $dataModel)
    ;
    ...
}
```

Comment: More acceptable answer and best practices are used here.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible out-of-box today (Mar 18 '12). You could, however, do something like this:

**in your controller:**

```
....
....

$post_route = null;
if ( $something ){
    $post_route = "some_post_route";
}else if ( $something_else ){
    $post_route = "some_other_post_route"
}else{
    $post_route = "my_default_route";
}

....
....

return array(
    'post_route' => $post_route
);
```

**... and in you template:**

```
<form action="{ path(post_route) }" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
```

Similar approach would be to generate URL (not just route name) within your controller and pass it to template, in which case you don't need `path` function there.

Comment: Thanks!  It is an odd dependency that we can't set the form and submit button values in the form class.

Comment: This answer is entirely incorrect. You can set the form action/method/etc in the controller, service, or even in the twig template.

Comment: Then care to show how, if you're using custom `FormType`? I am always open to a better solution. Also, please note the date of my answer - more than two and a half years ago.

Comment: @Acyra Can you please "unaccept" my answer? Both other answers offer better solutions.